# On :before pseudo element, input [type="button"] click is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I add an icon on `input type="button"` using pseudo element `::before` wrapping it in `span`, the **click for the `button` is not working when clicking on the icon**.

What solution could I use to move further? Below is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    alert('alert');
  });
});
```

```css
.um-searchwp .f_left {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.f_left {
  float: left;
}
.um-searchbtn.text-search {
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
}
.um-autosearchtext input.text {
  padding: 6px 29px 6px 5px;
  width: 192px;
  border: 1px solid #fd6800;
  color: #61381b;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.um-searchbtn input[type='button'] {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  background: #fd6800;
  border: 1px solid #fd6800;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.text-search::before {
  content: "i";
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url(../images/imageSprite.png) -237px -1084px;
  right: 8px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="f_left um-autosearchtext">
  <span class="um-searchbtn text-search">
 <input type="text" class="text f_left mr0 mb0" id="textboxSearchUser">
<input type="button" class = "btn" class="mr0 mb0">
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: *"click for the button is not working when clicking on the icon"* Well, no, because a click on the icon isn't a click on the button, it's a click on the pseudo-element in *front* of the button. Make your button a `button` and put the icon *inside* it.

Comment: There are no pseudo-element on `input`, in many browsers at least (because it's a replaced element or has no content as a self-closing tag [see that answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/137626)). Using `button[type='button']` which accepts and needs content would be more appropriate as stated by T.J. Crowder previously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM at all so you can't bind any events directly to them, you can only bind to their parent elements, like you have. The event doesn't bubble up to the parent element when the pseudo element is clicked though. Try adding the icon as a background-image

You could try something like this:

```js
         $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.btn').click(function() {
             alert('alert');
           });
         });
```

```css
p .f_left {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.f_left {
  float: left;
}
.um-searchbtn.text-search {
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
}
.um-autosearchtext input.text {
  padding: 6px 29px 6px 5px;
  width: 192px;
  border: 1px solid #fd6800;
  color: #61381b;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.um-searchbtn input[type='button'] {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  background: #fd6800;
  border: 1px solid #fd6800;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.text-search {
  padding-right: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url(../images/imageSprite.png) -237px -1084px;
  right: 8px;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="f_left um-autosearchtext">
  <span class="um-searchbtn text-search">
     <input type="text" class="text f_left mr0 mb0" id="textboxSearchUser">
    <input type="button" class = "btn" class="mr0 mb0">
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

not use pseudo element "before" and make value to input something like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="f_left um-autosearchtext">
  <span class="um-searchbtn text-search">
 <input type="text" class="text f_left mr0 mb0" id="textboxSearchUser">
<input type="button" class = "btn" class="mr0 mb0" value="i">
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: **i** is not actually a value, but it is supposed to be an image

Comment: in this cas putting background image to the input will resolve